# iText spacing inbetween paragraph

Tags: itextpdf

```
 managerp4.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
 managerp4.add(managerVO.getManagerAddress().getRoad2());

 managerp4.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);
 managerp4.add(managerVO.getManagerAddress().getRoad3());
```

This will generate output in newline like this

```
Road 2 
Road 3
```

but i want to display in same line with space between two values

Answer (score 1):

you can use the method `com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph.setSpacingAfter(float)` as follows:

**Example**

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This a string");
p.setSpacingAfter(10);
```